# MySQL AND as optional

Tags: mysql, mariadb

```
AND t1.Team IN (SELECT Team FROM t2 WHERE t3.ID = t2.ID)
```

How can I make above AND as optional, if the sub-query does not have any results, do not even consider `AND t1.Team IN ("")`.

Something like this does not work:

```
AND IF((SELECT Team FROM t2 WHERE t3.ID = t2.ID), (t1.Team IN (SELECT Team FROM t2 WHERE t3.ID = t2.ID)), 1)
```

Comment: Please explain why you wish to do this and add sample data and expected outcome as text to help clarify. NB you cannot make code optional so a different approach is required.

Answer (score 2):

Formally you need in

```
AND (    t1.Team IN (SELECT Team FROM t2 WHERE t3.ID = t2.ID)
      OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT Team FROM t2 WHERE t3.ID = t2.ID)
      )
```

But moving this subquery to FROM clause with proper left-joining seems to be more reasonable in your case.

Comment: how would you implement it with left-join?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Case Statement for check if else condition inside the SQL query syntax.

For that I think your query looks like below:

```
AND 
  CASE 
    WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t2 WHERE t3.ID = t2.ID) > 0 THEN t1.Team IN (SELECT Team FROM t2 WHERE t3.ID = t2.ID)
    ELSE 1=1
  END
```

Comment: EXISTS is more fast than COUNT().

Answer (score 0):

Might be bit faster to do (if t1.Team is not NULL):

```
AND t1.Team IN (
  SELECT Team FROM t2 WHERE t3.ID = t2.ID 
  UNION 
  SELECT t1.Team
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice trick to keep the query simple and good performance:

```
AND IFNULL(
(
    SELECT  MAX(IIF(t1.Team = t2.Team, 1, 0))
    FROM    t2
    WHERE   t3.ID       =   t2.ID
), 1)       =   1
```

explanation:

this sub-query does the following:

1. compare all rows in t2 to t1 by Team
2. if any matching Team- will return 1, else 0
3. if no rows at all in t2- will return NULL
4. the IFNULL will transform result of NULL to 1
5. so we expect the result of the sub-query to be 1

---

This means 1 will be returned from sub-query in 2 cases:

- if no rows are found in t2
- or if a matching Team found in t2

Comment: This will not return `Team`s from `t2` to apply the IN operator for: `AND t1.Team IN (SELECT Team FROM t2 WHERE t3.ID = t2.ID)` in case there are matching rows.

Comment: @forpas, instead of having an IN condition I chose to use a different approach, which covered the author's needs